# How to convert json string to an object in c#, then access it's property dynamiclly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have page that sends ajax request using jQuery to a server. The ajax request will `POST` json string to the server.

At the server side, I need to be able to convert the json string into an c# object.

Once, I convert the json string into an object I need to be able to loop thru it and alter the data.

Here is my json string

```
{'123':{'name': 'VALUE','campaign_id': 'VALUE 2'} }
```

Here is how I am trying to convert it to an object, then looping thru it.

```
    try
    {
        string json = Request["data"];

        dynamic records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        string longname = "";

        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            longname += record.name.ToString();
        }

        return longname;

    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        return e.ToString();
    }
```

But this is giving me this error

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' does not contain a definition for
>   'name' at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) at myController

How can I fix this issue?

**UPDATED**
Here is How the variable look in the debugger 
[image]

Comment: Why are you not just binding directly to a model (all this is handled out of the box by MVC)? You need to show the signature of your controller method, the model you trying to bind and the ajax code.

Comment: how would I do that? the json string will have a list of records

Comment: To repeat - _You need to show the signature of your controller method, the model you trying to bind and the ajax code_

Comment: I actually need it to be dynamic as I need to alter the data. how would I access the properties from the record object?

Comment: Your current example doesn't show any need to be dynamic. And why did you put jQuery in the title?

Comment: I am not sure why people vote down a question like this! @mason I just posted an example of the data but the json strong has a lot more data. I just left a sample to show that I need to do.

Comment: So how do you know what type you want to convert it to? And again, why did you put jQuery in your title?

Comment: @mason Everything should be string. jQuery way a typo in the question title, and instead of people leaving comment to help they just voted down the question with 0 helpful comment :). I just corrected my question

Comment: I feel like I'm having to repeat myself a lot here. So again, how do you know what type you want to convert it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the debug screenshot, try `record.Value.name` to get the value you are trying to read.

Though the JSON data has the property names in lowercase, the deserializer is using Camel Casing for the property names in the generated `dynamic` instance and C# property names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking to do is capture the json that is coming over into a C# class, and the json is static you can use the 'Paste JSON As Classes' ability.

More about that here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc/

Answer (score -3):

Less secure way but works in a pinch:
var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');

Comment: Look at the question. Despite the misleading title, it appears he's converting the object on the server.